# Drupal webform. Загрузка одновременно нескольких файлов

Tags: drupal, webforms

Нужно добавить в форму поле для загрузки нескольких файлов. Я использовал модуль https://drupal.org/project/webform_multifile, но он позволяет добавлять файлы только по-одному (один за другим). Есть ли альтернатива или как по другому решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/hadsie/1143186
Ему нужна jquery библиотека [Multiple file upload](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

Лучшая альтернатива - это свой модуль